# XmlSerializer Caching Factory

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0, factory-pattern, xmlserializer

I [came across a factory class](http://dotnetcodebox.blogspot.com.au/2013/01/xmlserializer-class-may-result-in.html#comment-form) and I'm not entirely sure how to use it if I am wanting to replace the following `XmlSerializer` code.

**Sample Model**

```
public class SampleData
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
}
```

**Existing Code**

```
List<SampleData> objects = new List<SampleData>();
objects.Add(new SampleData() { Country = "Australia", Name = "aus" });

StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();

XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<SampleData>));
serializer.Serialize(writer, objects);
```

**Factory Class**

```
public static class CachingXmlSerializerFactory
{
    private static readonly Dictionary<string, XmlSerializer> Cache = new Dictionary<string, XmlSerializer>();

    private static readonly object SyncRoot = new object();

    public static XmlSerializer Create(Type type, XmlRootAttribute root)
    {
        if (type == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("type");
        if (root == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("root");

        var key = String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "{0}:{1}", type, root.ElementName);

        lock (SyncRoot)
        {
            if (!Cache.ContainsKey(key))
            {
                Cache.Add(key, new XmlSerializer(type, root));
            }
        }

        return Cache[key];
    }

    public static XmlSerializer Create<T>(XmlRootAttribute root)
    {
        return Create(typeof(T), root);
    }

    public static XmlSerializer Create<T>()
    {
        return Create(typeof(T));
    }

    public static XmlSerializer Create<T>(string defaultNamespace)
    {
        return Create(typeof(T), defaultNamespace);
    }

    public static XmlSerializer Create(Type type)
    {
        return new XmlSerializer(type);
    }

    public static XmlSerializer Create(Type type, string defaultNamespace)
    {
        return new XmlSerializer(type, defaultNamespace);
    }
}
```

Comment: IIRC, `XmlSerializer` already internally performs caching based on types so instantiating new ones for the same type over and over again are fast. Do you expect to achieve measurable performance gains doing this? EDIT: And what was the _specific_ problem you had with what you tried? "tried to use the following with no avail" doesn't help too much.

Comment: Ahh disregard me in regards to comments about performance; this is about memory leaks (though in my experience with the `XmlSerializer`, I haven't had memory issues)

Comment: @ChrisSinclair To increase performance, the XML serialization infrastructure dynamically generates assemblies to serialize and deserialize specified types. The infrastructure finds and reuses those assemblies. -- I didn't realise it internally performs caching based on types. What I am after is to limit the amount of memory leakage that may be occurring. We execute a lot of `XmlSerialization` in a single application run.

Comment: That's fine, what's the specific problem you're having? I don't see anything immediately obvious that's wrong with your current usage.

Comment: Another question: would it be an option to use a ConcurrentDictionary here and remove the lock code?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Reread the section that article quotes from MSDN. You're already using one of the two constructors that caches the internal serializer, and thus it should not result in a memory leak. If you were using one of the other constructors, you would need to worry about caching the `XmlSerializer`, but you are not. No need to fix what isn't broken. ;-)